# Error inflating class <unknown> when changing style to android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Tags: android, styles, runtime-error, layout-inflater

I get this error when launching my application. I don't know why I get this
when adding `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` to my application  `Style`:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.metao.recorder/com.metao.recorder.activities.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML
>   file line #15: Error inflating class 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22:
>   Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class 
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                             at
>   com.metao.recorder.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:156)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  error
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15:
>   Error inflating class 
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)

My manifest is like this:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

My `v21/styles.xml` file is this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And `styles.xml` file is this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Can Someone help me please?

Comment: provode your xml and java code with quetion

Answer (score -1):

Modifiy manifest as below and check.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem: In of the resources in one Android Library, I have used this in my `LinearLayout`:

```
android:background="?attr/round_corners"
```

Which caused the program to crash and say `<unknown>` resources.

Thanks for all.